# Campos Select y Option

Tags: javascript, php, html-select, options

Estoy creando un formulario para clientes, pero al momento de seleccionar el municipio o ciudad, me guarda el `value` y no el texto, a continuación dejo el código de lo que tengo:

```html
<div class="form-group col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
  <label for="municipioAgregarDatos">MUNICIPIO <strong class="text-danger">*</strong></label>
  <select class="form-control  mayusc text-uppercase" id="municipioAgregarDatos"
    name="municipioAgregarDatos" maxlength="60">
    <option value="1">Ahuachapán</option>
    <option value="2">Apaneca</option>
    <option value="3">Atiquizaya</option>
    <option value="4">Concepción de Ataco</option>
    <option value="5">El Refugio</option>
    <option value="6">Guaymango</option>
    <option value="7">Jujutla</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

He intentado hacer algo con JS, pero no me funcionó, espero que alguien pueda darme una breve ayuda en lo que estoy intentando resolver.

Comment: Agrega a la pregunta lo que dijiste que intentaste hacer.

Comment: y si también pones los textos en los values?...

Answer (score 0):

Pues lo harías teniendo el texto en tus `values`, y al enviar el formulario envías esos `values`:

```js
function getValue(value) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
  <label for="municipioAgregarDatos">MUNICIPIO <strong class="text-danger">*</strong></label>
  <select class="form-control  mayusc text-uppercase" id="municipioAgregarDatos" onchange="getValue(this.value)"
    name="municipioAgregarDatos" maxlength="60">
    <option value="Ahuachapán">Ahuachapán</option>
    <option value="Apaneca">Apaneca</option>
    <option value="Atiquizaya">Atiquizaya</option>
    <option value="Concepción de Ataco">Concepción de Ataco</option>
    <option value="El Refugio">El Refugio</option>
    <option value="Guaymango">Guaymango</option>
    <option value="Jujutla">Jujutla</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

O si quieres hacerlo con js, podrías utilizar [**`Document.querySelector()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) para obtener el texto del valor que seleccionas de la siguiente forma:

```js
function getValue(value) {
  let select = document.querySelector("#municipioAgregarDatos option[value='" + value + "']:checked").text;
  console.log(select);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
  <label for="municipioAgregarDatos">MUNICIPIO <strong class="text-danger">*</strong></label>
  <select class="form-control  mayusc text-uppercase" id="municipioAgregarDatos" onchange="getValue(this.value)"
    name="municipioAgregarDatos" maxlength="60">
    <option value="1">Ahuachapán</option>
    <option value="2">Apaneca</option>
    <option value="3">Atiquizaya</option>
    <option value="4">Concepción de Ataco</option>
    <option value="5">El Refugio</option>
    <option value="6">Guaymango</option>
    <option value="7">Jujutla</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: El problema es que al seleccionar un departamento aparece la lista de municipios que pertenecer a ese departamento, y esta sujeto al value de los departamentos.

Al seleccionar municipio 1, 2  3, se despliega la lista con otros estados

Comment: algo parecido a mi segundo ejemplo, podrías hacer una condicional (js o php) de que si el `value` (que recibe como parámetro la función) es `1`, sea igual al texto del `value` 1, así sucesivamente, y el resultado almacenar en una variable, y esa variable enviar en el post de tu formulario.